# Importing a dll from a different compiler

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder

I have compiled a library that I have created with MinGW into an existing application using Borland 6 (I know its old but that's what it was made with). I have used implib to create the .lib file and imported it into my project. I have also added the paths to the dll and necessary header files.

When I try to compile I get a pile of Unnresolved external type errors. Have I missed out any steps of the importing process? Assuming I haven't and the issue is something like name-mangling how do I go about writing the interface in such a way that name mangling won't matter. I know it involves extern C but thats about the limit of my knowledge. There are only two classes that need to be accessed from outside the dll the remainder are all only used internally. I'm not sure how to use extern C with something that is entirely built with classes. I'm stil hopeful that it's my importing with borland 6.

Comment: There is a good FAQ (with a code examples) concerning your issue. Beware that it concerns mostly linux. But I hope it helps you anyway http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/C++-dlopen.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extern "C" cannot be used for classes, only for free functions. So you have an option of writing a "C" interface to your class, where each function takes a pointer to your class and you would probably have create and destroy functions.

This is a way it is typically done, and your class could be forwardly declared as struct, which is the same as class, and then could even be used by applications written in C. You would normally put extern "C" only when __cplusplus is defined so there are normally #ifdef guards around it.

There is another option, if you only want your class to be used by C++ and you don't want to have to write a C interface for all your class methods.

Users of the DLL use an abstract interface and still use Create and Destroy methods (with extern "C") to create a pointer to the abstract interface, but then use the pointer in the normal C++ way. Of course ideally you will wrap this pointer in a smart pointer, e.g. a boost shared_ptr with a custom deleter that calls the Destroy method. (Users of the library should do that but you can provide a headers-only interface to do it).

There are a few other issues you would need to beware of if doing this, e.g. anything to do with run-time type information is likely to not work on the user-side, including exceptions. And once again your library could provide "open-source" C++ wrappers (compiled on the client side) to handle this in a more C++ way. A sort-of pImpl.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see this being an educational day, I'll probably turn my two accessing classes into one. In the interests of not making a aside task take a long time and at the risk of a backlash is there any benefit to making that class a singleton and having my C-style functions operate on that?

Comment: Why does it need to be a singleton? That would be done if you must only have one of them and you need it to be globally available without having it passed as a parameter.

Comment: There shold only be one instance of the interface class as it happens, I've been trying to kick the singleton habit when I have a 'manager' type of class. I was wondering whether it might be useful here because there would be a single pointer for the C functions to call, maybe it doesn't help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The name mangling is not standardized across compilers. Only expose **extern C** functions so that they are not name mangled. But this has a limitation that you cannot use object orient programming.

Another option is to implement COM objects as they are binary compatible.